# localhost:5001 refusing connection with VS Code for OSX

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to run a test ASP.NET Application on OSX using VS Code that is explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5). After running dnx: kestrel and navigating to localhost:5001 I get a Connection Refused.

What can be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's localhost:5000. If anyone is following that tutorial, keep that in mind.

Comment: That's incorrect.  It's https://localhost:5001 or http://localhost:5000.

Answer (score 3):

By default, it should listen on both ports

- http://localhost:5000 (http)
- https://localhost:5001 (httpS)

If you see `Connection Refused` it may mean that your machine does not trust HTTPS development certificate used.

You may need to run

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

in order to trust HTTPS certificate.

More details and platform specific information is available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos